# File Missing after Zip Load

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to import a CSV file as a Pandas data frame.  The files are included in a larger Zip file. Below is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

DataURL = "file:///c:/Users/MMoynihan/Desktop/TensorFlow/DNN_Dataset/SIM_IMGS.zip"
TagURL = "file:///c:/Users/MMoynihan/Desktop/TensorFlow/DNN_Dataset/SIM_TAGS.zip"
TagName1 = 'Sim_TAG0_2021-08-13-18-52.csv'

data_for_processing = keras.utils.get_file('plots', DataURL)
tags_for_processing = keras.utils.get_file('tags', DataURL)

zf = zipfile.ZipFile(tags_for_processing)
df = pd.read_csv(zf.open(TagName1))
```

For whatever reason, the tagged file is not listed as being part of the larger Zip file.

```
raise KeyError(
KeyError: "There is no item named 'Sim_TAG0_2021-08-13-18-52.csv' in the archive"
```

I tested 4 or 5 different file names that I know are present, but none of these came up as listed in the zip.

====

I have a similar problem accessing the image files.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

DataURL = "file:///c:/Users/MMoynihan/Desktop/TensorFlow/DNN_Dataset/SIM_IMGS.zip"
TagURL = "file:///c:/Users/MMoynihan/Desktop/TensorFlow/DNN_Dataset/SIM_TAGS.zip"

TagTest = 'Sim_TAG7_2021-08-13-18-52.csv'
ImageTest = 'Sim_Image1_2021-08-13-18-52.png'

IMG_processing = keras.utils.get_file('plots', DataURL)
TAGS_processing = keras.utils.get_file('tags', DataURL)

archive = zipfile.ZipFile(IMG_processing, 'r')
imgdata = archive.read(ImageTest)
```

Below are the errors:

```
Raise KeyError(KeyError: "There is no item named 'Sim_Image1_2021-08-13-18-52.png' in the archive"
```

Comment: Why there is a 7 (TAG7) instead of 0 (TAG0) in the error message?

Comment: Used different file names. "There is no item named 'Sim_TAG1_2021-08-13-18-52.csv' in the archive".  There is no item named 'Sim_TAG7_2021-08-13-18-52.csv' in the archive". "There is no item named 'Sim_TAG0_2021-08-13-18-52.csv' in the archive".

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.  The filename must include the zip folder in which it resides.  in this case:

```
TagTest = 'SIM_TAGS/Sim_TAG7_2021-08-13-18-52.csv'
ImageTest = 'SIM_IMGS`/Sim_Image1_2021-08-13-18-52.png'
```